# Trim video using YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube-data-api

I understand that you can trim the video using the youtube.com interface but I was wondering if it is possible to use the YouTube Data API to trim the video.

Since I don't user to upload video on my site longer than 15 seconds.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

API example (according to http://www.youtube.com/player_api)  to TRIM with **START** and **END** parameters: 
http://rawgit.com/tazotodua/several-YOUTUBE-PLAYER-SCRIPTS__with_API/master/example99-CUTTER/index.html

Comment: This only trim the playback video, not the video itselft like you can do in the YouTube user interface.