# Trimming videos with YoutTube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

Is it possible to trim existing videos on my YouTube channel and save them as new videos? I've googled the question and found questions without the correct answers, example here: [Trim video using YouTube Data API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867364/trim-video-using-youtube-data-api)